# Java SDK on NixOS for IntelliJ

Tags: java, nixos, intellij

I have recently installed NixOS on my machine, 
for Java development I have added IntelliJ CE 14.1.5 and the Oracle JDK 8.

However IntelliJ does not automatically recognize the path to the Java SDK

```
readlink -f $(which java)
/nix/store/...-oraclejdk-8u60/bin/java
```

when selecting /bin/ in the "Select Home Directory for JDK" it does not accept it.

I have been searching around for some time now but I can't really find the right stuff to get it working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does intellij produce some error log you can share? i guess intellij wants to write to /nix/store/...-oraclejdk-8u60

Answer (score 0):

Try

`/nix/store/...-oraclejdk-8u60/`

Intellij expects the root of `JAVA_HOME`, and appends `bin/java` itself.